# Parsing a newline-terminated programming language

Tags: parsing

Recently i've been trying to develop a custom programming language. But where the previous languages I (attempted to) make were semicolon-terminated the language I'm now making is terminated by a newline, just like Python.

The problem I've stumbled across was that while every semicolon in e.g. C++ is treated as a terminator of sorts, a newline in Python does not always act as a terminator.

For example:

```c
// incorrect in c++
myfunc();;;;otherfunc();
```

and

```py
# completely fine in python
myfunc()



otherfunc()
```

So my question is, how do i parse this? What does the backus-naur form of a language like this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about C++, but in many semicolon-terminated languages, `;;` is perfectly valid. [Example in PHP](https://3v4l.org/FdGpI)

A simple way to express this in the abstract grammar is to allow an empty statement - that is, one made up only of optional whitespace. The parser can then accept this as valid, but emit nothing.

In [the PHP parser](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L525), one of the productions for `statement` is this:

```
';' /* empty statement */ { $$ = NULL; }
```

The same rule could be used (mutatis mutandis) in a grammar where newline was treated as a significant token, rather than grouped into whitespace.